# Changing Units in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Im creating a cooking website sort of thing.

So I have a table with all ingredients needed, and you should change the amount of portions you want to cook.

So I got a few problems with that:

https://jsfiddle.net/t5tovvs7/5/

```js
window.moreportions = function() {
var number = document.getElementById("number").value
var table = document.getElementById("table");
var rowCount = document.getElementById('table').rows.length;
for (i = 1;i < rowCount;i++) {
var text = table.rows[i].cells[0].innerHTML;
var unit = text.split(" ");
var newnumber = unit[0] * number
table.rows[i].cells[0].innerHTML = newnumber
}
}
```

```html
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/new.css">
<table class="table" id="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Anzahl</th>
      <th>Zutat</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <!-- Erste Reihe -->
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>0.25 kg</td>
      <td>Tomaten</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

  <!-- Zweite Reihe -->
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>0.5</td>
      <td>Zwiebel</td>
    </tr>

    <!-- Vorlage  Anfang -->

  </tbody>
</table>
<input id="number" type="number">
<button onclick="moreportions();">Calculate</button>
<!-- jQuery first, then Tether, then Bootstrap JS. -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

First off: I need to multiply the numbers **without** the units, so make 1 kg out of 0.25 kg when you want 4 portions.

Is it good practice to do this via splitting the text ("`1 kg`") by spaces, so we have `1` and `kg` and then just multiplying the first number?

Secondly:
As seen in the second row, some things cant be given in kilogram, or gram. In this case onions :D

Can I somehow make ½ and so on also getting multiplied?

And if you, as an example, want to make 4 portions and click the button, it is getting multiplied by 4, but If you decide you only want 2 portions and click it again, you are getting 8 portions.
How can I save the base number (in the case of the tomatoes, 0.25, and the onions, 0.5) so that the number is accurate?

Comment: Where do you buy those big big big tomatoes?

Comment: To be fair, I'm not sure of what you want. Could you explain what you need a bit further?

Comment: what part didnt you understand

Comment: You should simply have a function that convert string (with unit) to numbers and number to string (with units). That way, you take your input, keep the units in mind, but converts everythings in numbers, do your maths, then when everything is calculated and ready to be printed, you give it to your formatting function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want to preserve the original data, and the original units, and use those each time you're asked to recalculate. Simply save them as units on the element itself, then use THEM rather than the actual text each time you recalculate.

Here's one way.

```js
var calcButton = document.getElementsByClassName("calculate")[0];
var qtyInput = document.querySelector("#quantity")
var ingredientQtyEls = document.querySelectorAll("td.recipe-quantity");

// For the sake of preserving the original quantities and units,
//    we'll save them as an attribute on the element itself
for (i=0; i<ingredientQtyEls.length; i++){
  var origString = ingredientQtyEls[i].innerText;
  // This will remove all the numeric bits, so we have the unit
  var origUnit = origString.replace(/[-()\d//*+.]/g, '');
  // This does the exact opposite -- keep the qty and eval fractions.
  var origAmt = eval(origString.replace(/[^-()\d/*+.]/g, '') );
  
  // Now, we save them as attributes.
  ingredientQtyEls[i].origAmt = origAmt;
  ingredientQtyEls[i].origUnit = origUnit;
  
}


calcButton.addEventListener("click", function(){
  // When the calculate button is clicked, we should go ahead and
  //  iterate over the quantity els and update them as appropriate.
  var quantity = qtyInput.value;
  
  // We iterate over each row we've saved,
  for (i=0; i<ingredientQtyEls.length; i++){
    // retrieve the original amount, 
    var startingAmt = ingredientQtyEls[i].origAmt;
    
    // And update the innerText to the orig amount times quantity.
    ingredientQtyEls[i].innerText = quantity*startingAmt+" "+ingredientQtyEls[i].origUnit;
    
  }
  
})
```

```html
<table class="table" id="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="recipe-quantity">Anzahl</th>
      <th class="recipe-ingredient">Zutat</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <!-- Erste Reihe -->
  <tbody>
    <tr class="ingredient-row">
      <td class="recipe-quantity">0.25 kg</td>
      <td class="recipe-ingredient">Tomaten</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="ingredient-row">
      <td class="recipe-quantity">1/2</td>
      <td class="recipe-ingredient">Zwiebel</td>
    </tr>

    <!-- Vorlage  Anfang -->

  </tbody>
</table>
<input id="quantity" type="number">
<button class="calculate">Calculate</button>
```

Comment: Interesting, I can make 0.3242342 as a portion.

Comment: @Roberrt its ok, Ill fix it :D